# Automation to renew ADO PAT

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to evaluate and implement a way to automatically renew PATs owned by the service account our ADO is running under, like a scheduled task or something that runs on the previous day before the expiration date, and sends the PAT in an email to an AD group.
In short, some automatic way to renew PAT and notify a set of users with the new PAT OR automatically update the expiration date when it is due for expiry

I am aware of the REST API that uses Azure AD tokens (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/manage-personal-access-tokens-via-api?view=azure-devops#authenticate-with-azure-active-directory-azure-ad-tokens) but the service account does not have an account in the Azure portal and I want to avoid using an employee's token.

I am curious to know what the best practices are and how you have designed it out in your org. Thank you very much for the help!